# Speed up Excel formulas

Tags: excel

Is there anyway to rewrite this formula to speed up Excel processing?

My spreadsheet has become terribly slow!

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!J:J=Sheet2!A2)*(Sheet1!G:G="Windows XP")*(Sheet1!B:B="Desktop")*(Sheet1!M:M<>"Refresh >=Q2 2014")*(Sheet1!M:M<>"Release 2013")*(Sheet1!M:M<>"Release 2014")*(Sheet1!M:M<>"N/A NVM")*(Sheet1!M:M="No")*(Sheet1!M:M="N/A"))
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: The formula above is what I have at the moment - I need some help rewriting it to make it faster

Comment: Your approach is extremely cumbersome. Think about where you are repeating the same operation multiple times and try to remove that duplication of effort. It may be that you simply need to use a proper database rather than Excel to experience material speed improvements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written your formula will always return zero because the last two conditions are mutually exclusive - did you mean those last two to be <> rather than = (or did you refer to the wrong columns)?

In any case I can see from the use of whole columns that you must be using `Excel 2007` or later (your current formula would give an error otherwise) in which case `COUNTIFS` will be much faster, i.e. assuming the last two conditions should be adjusted as I suggested try this version:

`=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!J:J,Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!G:G,"Windows XP",Sheet1!B:B,"Desktop",Sheet1!M:M,"<>Refresh >=Q2 2014",Sheet1!M:M,"<>Release 2013",Sheet1!M:M,"<>Release 2014",Sheet1!M:M,"<>N/A NVM",Sheet1!M:M,"<>No",Sheet1!M:M,"<>N/A")`

If you **do** need to use SUMPRODUCT then restrict the ranges rather than using whole columns

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that there is really a chance to speed up Excel Formula. But you could save your File in binary code (.xlsb). Losing some compatibility but improving performance.

You also could stop auto (re-)calculations of ther Formula, then you have to manualy refresh. This will let you edit the file much smoother.